# aura:if prevents 'onload' of lightning recordEditform to be called

Tags: lightning, lightning-recordeditform, aura-if

I create a Lightning component which loads an Opportunity record with recordEditForm. In this component, I want to display areas conditionnally. I am using aura:if/aura:set tags sequence for that. The aura:if is supposed to show or hide data displayed using inputField, so it is embedded in the recordEditForm tags.

The 'aura:if isTrue' is based on information in the Opportunity record (isClosed field). So I handle the 'onload' event triggered by the recordEditForm to get the value.

The problem: in this configuration, the 'onload' function is not called. If I remove the aura:if/aura:set sequence, then 'onload' is called.

The component code :

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="showarea" type="boolean"/>

    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="SearchRooms"
                              objectApiName="Opportunity"
                              recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                              onload="{!c.hOnload}"
    >
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showarea}" >
            <lightning:messages/>
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="isClosed" class="slds-hidden" />

            <lightning:card class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                <lightning:button variant="brand" value="btnSearchRooms" aura:id="btnSearchRooms" label="{!$Label.c.Search}"
                                  onclick="{!c.hSearchRooms}" type="submit"/>
                <lightning:button variant="brand" value="btnEnregistrer" aura:id="btnEnregistrer"
                                  label="{!$Label.c.Submit_Resident}" onclick="{!c.hSubmitRequests}" type="submit"/>
            </lightning:card>

            <lightning:accordion allowMultipleSectionsOpen="true" activeSectionName="Profile" >
                <lightning:accordionSection label="Requester Profile" name="Profile" >
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters slds-m-around_large">
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="NeurologicalManagement__c"/>
                        </div>
.
.
        <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div>
                    <p>Opportunity.isClosed is True</p>
                </div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

The controller code

```
    hOnload: function( cmp, evt, helper )  {

        var data = evt.getParam("recordUi");
        var isClosed = data.record.fields["IsClosed"].value;
        if( !isClosed ) {
                cmp.set("v.showarea", true);
        }
        else
            cmp.set("v.showarea", false);
    },
```

Is it normal ?
What might be a workaround ?

Thank you

Comment: The onload action triggered when the form data is loaded. In your case when component loads your lightning:recordEditForm is not visible because your "showarea" attribute is false by default and that's why it is not calling your on load function.

Comment: from my experience working with `Aura` I would suggest not using `if:true` at all, because I think it's too buggy

Comment: @ShagunSharma You're right : giving a value to the showarea variable makes the handler to be called. Thank you.